# invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query but for reason its keep giving me below error

> ORA-00904: "DISTANCE_IN_METRES": invalid identifier

can someone please help to sort the issue, much appreciated for any help or guidance on this.

Comment: Perhaps its "distance_in_meters"?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a column defined in a select clause in that same select clause. Logically a select clause is evaluated all at once. A simplified example:

```
select 1 as test, 2 * test from dual

ORA-00904: "TEST": invalid identifier
```

As kashi points out in a comment, `DISTANCE_IN_METRES` is referenced in the case expression following the definition of `DISTANCE_IN_METRES` in the same select clause, and this is where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks Shannon that make sense, appreciated your help.